Kitchen sink stops draining, then resumes once toilet is flushed
A strange occurrence has happened twice in one week at my home.
The first occurrence: my wife was using the toilet and flushed lots of toilet paper, which slowed the emptying of the toilet bowl, but it did end up emptying. As she was flushing, I was using the kitchen sink and water draining temporarily stopped and water began accumulating in the sink. Draining only resumed once I went to flush the toilet a second time. When the kitchen sink was emptying, I heard a big gurgling sound, as if a big air bubble passed through, and I think the p trap under the sink might have emptied as well.
Second occurrence happened last night. I was using the kitchen sink and once again, water started accumulating and the sink was no longer emptying. However, this time, no one was using the toilet. I went to flush the toilet myself, and the same thing happened : big gurgle, then kitchen sink emptied.
I then went to the basement and noticed my washing machine (which was washing a load of clothes during this time) overflowed from the drain pipe. The last time I had my washing machine back up, it was due to the houses main drain going to the sewer being blocked with roots. The washing machine drain is the lowest drain so it overflows first if the main drain is blocked. We ended up clearing all the roots a couple years ago.
This morning, I ran a test and left 3 faucets fully open for 10 minutes to see if the main drain would back up. It didn't, so I'm pretty sure I don't have a clogged main drain.
I'm stumped for explanations to what has happened twice in the span of a few days. The fact that I can't explain it makes me worried to run appliances while I'm not home. The only thing I can think of is a temporary venting issue that caused negative pressure in the drain pipes and was relieved by flushing a large drain (the toilet). Does anyone have any insight?
Thanks


Look to the roof vent for the drains to see if it's blocked. 2. There could be waste  caught around roots that occasionally moves to block pipe. Are non-flushable items being used, such as diaper wipes (some are mislabeled as "flushable", though made of long-enduring fabric)? If so, the drains need to be augured.


No non flushables are being used. I'm thinking of DIYing a drain inspection camera  (as per https://youtu.be/hvl7p2g8ATk?si=ADn6XBbBFAHQLu6Z) and running it down my vent and drains to take a look
